# How to customize submenus isn wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress theme and in the header.php file it is displaying menus through this line :

```
wp_nav_menu( 'theme_location=menu_2&menu_id=nav&container=&fallback_cb=menu_2_default');
```

Now if I hover some menu item, it displays submenus items. I just want to change the layout of the submenu items section or div , but I can't find any html of submenus. I need help in this

Answer (score 0):

This is within your css. Since we don't have a link to your website we could only direct you to the most common place for it. (use dev tools to inspect them)

SOMETHING like this in your CSS

```
.menu-top-navigation-container {...}

// first list item 
#menu ul li {..}
//second list item
#menu ul li ul li{...}
//second list item linkable text
menu ul li ul li a{...}
```

This is all hypothetical. Your theme will most definitely be different but this is where you style them.

Comment: I need only to change CSS when I want to change submenu style i.e. colour , size etc .  I want to change layout of submenu , which is editing the HTML

Comment: @user1700794, please, add more details and clarifications *to the Question itself*. As you can see, right now, there are not enough elements to provide a precise Answer.